# app fails to install ad hoc on iPhone 3GS

Tags: iphone, ios, ad-hoc-distribution

one of my testers tells me that the ad hoc installation via iTunes of my app (built with XCode 4.6.3, deployment target iOS 5.0) fails with an error message ("cannot install") on the iPhone (3 GS, iOS 6.1.3).

It works well on iPhone 4, 4S, 5, iPad 2 models running iOS 5.1, 6.1.3 and on Simulator (iPhone, iOS 6.1).

Required device capabilities has only armv7. Startup screens exist for these sizes: 320x480, 640x960, 640x1136.

What else might be an issue with the iPhone 3GS?

TIA & regards,
Roland

Comment: I faced the same problem when giving `adhoc` build by taking app file from `Product>Archive` and then sending the `.app` file inside `xarchive` file. After that I tried to provide `.ipa` file by an option in XCode to Distribute the adhoc build and then it works on all devices.

Comment: make sure your iphone 3gs UDID is added in your provisioning

Comment: UDID has been added & ipa file was sent.

Comment: no, I had NOT added the new UDID to the profile, thanks Pradeep.